# Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a function, and $X\subseteq A$. Prove or disprove that $f(f^{-1}(f(X)))=f(X)$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

- Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a function, and $X\subseteq A$. Prove or disprove that $f(f^{-1}(f(X)))=f(X)$.

Let $A=\mathbb{N}$, $B=\mathbb{R}$ and $X=\mathbb{N\setminus\left\{0\right\}}.$ Hence, $f$ is not invertible so we don't have $f(f^{-1}(f(X)))=f(X)$ every time.

**Can you check my solution?**

Comment: What does invertibility of $f$ have to do with the statement?

Comment: If $f$ is not invertible, then $f^{-1}$ typically stands for the inverse image, which is defined for every relation.

Comment: As mentioned, $f^{-1}$ is indeed the inverse image.

Comment: thanks for comments, so how can I solve this question, can you give a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $b\in f(f^{-1}(f(X)))$. So $b=f(a)$ for some $a\in f^{-1}(f(X))$. By definition of $f^{-1}$, it follows that $f(a)\in f(X)$ and so $b\in f(X)$. We conclude that $f(f^{-1}(f(X)))\subseteq f(X)$.

Let $b\in f(X)$. So $b=f(a)$ for some $a\in X$. Then also $a\in f^{-1}(\{b\})\subseteq f^{-1}(f(X))$ and so $b=f(a)\in f(f^{-1}(f(X)))$. We conclude $f(X)\subseteq f(f^{-1}(f(X)))$.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Recall $f^{-1}(Y)=\{x: f(x)\in Y\}$.
Hint: Convince yourself that for any set $Y$ you have $f(f^{-1}(Y))\subset Y$ and $Y\subset f^{-1}(f(Y))$. What happens if  $Y=f(X)$ and $Y=X$ respectively?

Comment: Thanks for comments and hint.